# What does the message "Request for font "Noto Sans" blocked at visibility level 1 (requires 3) - node.js" implies and how to prevent it?

Tags: javascript, css, fonts

My website always displays this warning in the console :

```
"Request for font "Noto Sans" blocked at visibility level 1 (requires 3) - node.js"
```

Noto Sans is not loaded as a file by the website, it is only used as a backup font if other fonts do not display. Yet it is the only backup font where I get this warning.

What does this message mean and how to eventually prevent it ?

This is the full code of the page were the problem figures:

```html
<style>
.addFont {
  font-family: 'ui-sans-serif', 'system-ui', '-apple-system', 'BlinkMacSystemFont', 'Segoe UI',
    'Roboto', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Arial', 'Noto Sans', 'sans-serif', 'Apple Color Emoji',
    'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol', 'Noto Color Emoji';
}
</style>

<span class="addFont">Text</span>
```

Note: these fonts & fallback fonts are initially from the [TailwindCSS default "font-sans" class](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/font-family).

Comment: Please show the code that loads the font.

Comment: What browser are you using? Firefox has [this kind of visibility levels](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/rev/de15f9c109f9c474d00faf8032f559c236067c06/modules/libpref/init/StaticPrefList.yaml#7622-7650) implemented to prevent user installed fonts from loading from the local system, to reduce the possibility of fingerprinting by installed fonts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply removing the 'Noto Sans' and 'Noto Color Emoji' fallback fonts (in my case in TailwindCSS "font-sans") solved the problem.

It seems that the font was blocked by Firefox for preventing fingerprinting by installed fonts, as pointed out by @Christopher in comments.

Comment: If you provide the font from the server (for example: `@font-face { font-family: 'Noto Color Emoji'; src: url('/path/to/NotoColorEmoji.ttf') format('truetype'); }`), it wouldn't be blocked on the page by the privacy protection tools firefox has recently implemented.